# How to add a random computer choice to a button in rock paper scissors

Tags: javascript

I have the variables to generate the random number between 1-3 and have that return either 'rock' 'paper' or 'scissors' but, I cant figure out how to add that function into an event listener for the individual button that's been pressed. and have it return 'computer chose---'. Also, currently on button press the image changes but no selection of 'rock' 'paper' 'scissors' is actually made, can I add that inside the `playerChoice()` along with the image changing `onclick` or should that be its own function?

```
 <section>
        <div class="player1">
            <h2>Player One</h2>
            <p>0</p>
        </div>
        <div class="computer">
            <h2>Computer</h2>
            <p>0</p>
        </div>
        <div class="game-board">
            <img id="player-choice" src="images/rock.png" alt="" />
            <img id="computer-choice" src="images/rock.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="options-btn">
            <input type="button" id="rock-btn" value="Rock" />
            <input type="button" id="paper-btn" value="Paper" />
            <input type="button" id="scissors-btn" value="Scissors" />
        </div>
    </section>
```

```
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

function playerChoice() {
  const playerChoice = document.getElementById('player-choice');
  const rock = document.getElementById('rock-btn');
  const paper = document.getElementById('paper-btn');
  const scissors = document.getElementById('scissors-btn');
  rock.addEventListener('click', () => {
    playerChoice.src = 'images/rock.png';
  });
  paper.addEventListener('click', () => {
    playerChoice.src = 'images/paper.png';
  });
  scissors.addEventListener('click', () => {
    playerChoice.src = 'images/scissors.png';
  });
}

function computerChoice() {
  const options = document.querySelectorAll('.options-btn button');
  const randomPick = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  return (choice = randomPick[randomNumber]);
}

playerChoice();
```

Comment: It is probably not a smart idea to have a variable inside your function that has exactly the same name as the function. Even if it doesn't cause technical issues (which I'm not even sure), it still is really bad for refactoring and readability.

Comment: You're right I hadn't thought of that ill change that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get playerChoice with eventListener and compare choices with game() function

```
function game(userChoice) {
  const computerChoice = computerChoice();
  switch (userChoice + computerChoice) {
    case "rockscissors":
    case "paperrock":
    case "scissorspaper":
      win(userChoice, computerChoice);
      break;
    case "rockpaper":
    case "paperscissors":
    case "scissorsrock":
      lose(userChoice, computerChoice);
      break;
    case "rockrock":
    case "paperpaper":
    case "scissorscissors":
      draw(userChoice, computerChoice);
      break;
  }
}

function main() {
rock.addEventListener("click",function() {
  game("rock");
})

paper.addEventListener("click",function() {
  game("paper");
})

scissors.addEventListener("click",function() {
  game("scissors");
})
}

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an event listener here. It seems like you are over complicating it.

Since I don't know what your HTML looks like, I will assume there are three buttons for the player to choose:

HTML:

```
<img src="images/rock.png" onClick="playerChoice('rock');">
<img src="images/paper.png" onClick="playerChoice('paper');">
<img src="images/scissors.png" onClick="playerChoice('scissors');">
```

JS:

```
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

function playerChoice(pChoice) {
    const playerChoice = document.getElementById('player-choice');
    const rock = document.getElementById('rock-btn');
    const paper = document.getElementById('paper-btn');
    const scissors = document.getElementById('scissors-btn');
    if (pChoice== "rock") {
        playerChoice.src = 'images/rock.png';
    } else if (pChoice == "paper") {
        playerChoice.src = 'images/paper.png';
    } else if (pChoice == "scissors") {
        playerChoice.src = 'images/scissors.png';
    }
    var cChoice = computerChoice() ;
    
    // do your pChoice vs cChoice comparison:
    // increment playerScore/computerScore
}

function computerChoice() {
    const options = document.querySelectorAll('.options-btn button');
    const randomPick = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    return randomPick[randomNumber];
}
```